# Switching GoogleMap between activities

Tags: android

I have two activities one that send coordinates and one that recieves and drawing them.

I need that both of them will show GoogleMap... in the first activity i can see google map right away but then when i call to the second activity from BroadcastReceiver i just see blank white screen.

Thats my Second activity code:

```
public class NewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    String message;
    String number;
    double[] d = new double[4];
    ArrayList<LatLng>  points= new  ArrayList<LatLng>() ;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {

      super.onStart();
        final LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
       final IntentFilter localFilter = new IntentFilter();

      localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver, localFilter);
  }
@Override
    public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
      final LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =
               LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
           // Make sure to unregister!!
           localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver);
}

    BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()

        {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
           {
                setContentView(R.layout.ye);
                 SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                 googleMap = fm.getMap();
                 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                 message=intent.getStringExtra("message");
                 number=intent.getStringExtra("number");
                 int p=0;


                    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)").matcher(message);

                    while(m.find())
                    {
                       double  k = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
                       d[p]=k;
                       p++;
                       }




                 PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                 polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

                    // Setting the width of the polyline
                    polylineOptions.width(6);

                    // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList

                    LatLng coordlocation = new LatLng(d[0], d[1]);
                     points.add(coordlocation);
                     LatLng coordlocation2 = new LatLng(d[2], d[3]);
                     points.add(coordlocation2);


                    // Setting points of polyline
                    polylineOptions.addAll(points);
                    googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

           }
        };

}
```

Note : I didnt registered the localBroadcastReceiver in the manifest file since i dont know if its neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ye);
}
```